# Service Fabric Get-ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration not returning the latest config

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Whenever I run the Get-ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration commandlet after an upgrade, it shows the previous cluster configuration version, not the latest as it should.  Has anyone encountered this issue?